# SHOUTcast stream in Windows Phone 8

Tags: audio, stream, windows-phone-8, shoutcast

does anybody have an idea how I can play SHOUTcast streams in the audio player of Windows Phone 8?

I've already tried these links:
stream/
stream/;
stream/; stream.mp3

Any help is welcome!

Comment: All you need is `/;`.  So, if your SHOUTcast server is running on `10.11.12.13` on port `8000`, your stream URL is `http://10.11.12.13:8000/;`.  If that doesn't work, there is something wrong with your code, which is hard to help you with as you haven't posted it.

Answer (score 1):

This project is for Windows Phone 7 and it hasn't been update in a while; however, It worked fine for a couple of Windows Phone 8 applications I built.

http://shoutcastmss.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement this yourself. Not supported out of the box on WP unfortunately.